# Como percorrer CheckBox no WebForms gerado automaticamente com JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, checkbox

Como percorrer vários CheckBox no evento Click de um botão com C# sendo que esses CheckBox foram gerados automaticamente com JQuery ? 
O HTML do CheckBox gerado automaticamente é esse:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="MainContent_pnlCheckbox">
        <div id="MainContent_divCheckboxes">
            <div>
                <a>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chkCI" id="2" runat="server" checked="checked" value="2">
                        <span>CI 2</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chkCI" id="4" runat="server" checked="checked" value="4">
                        <span>CI 4</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O código para percorrer o CheckBox é ess:

```
foreach(Control item in divCheckboxes.Controls)
{
    if(item is CheckBox)
    {
        CheckBox c = item as CheckBox;
        if (c != null && c.Checked)
        {
            CIModel ci = new CIModel();
            ci.idci = int.Parse(c.ClientID);
            lCI.Add(ci);
        }
    }
}
```

Porém o código acima não encontra o objeto CheckBox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Estou usando uma MasterPage.

Comment: Coloque o aspx. :)

Answer (score 0):

Se eles foram gerados no JQuery ou simplesmente adicionados no html, eles só existem na tela do cliente e não no seu servidor. Ou seja não são componentes server side que foram renderizados pelo asp.net e você não conseguirá interagir com eles no c# como os demais controles.

Mas você consegue recuperar os valores selecionados através do `Request.Form`

```
var chkCI = Request.Form.GetValues("chkCI");
```